# After upload the code to ESP12F (esp8266) the windows COM serial port is disapeared

Tags: serial-port, esp8266, esp-12f

I bought an ESP12F (esp8266 series). My code a led blinker and works my old ESP12E. 
After I uploaded via my COM6 port and started the code on ESP12F then the windows COM6 port disapeared from my device manager :( 
The port apeared when I disconnect the USBtoSerial (CH340 based) device from my ESP12F. (The code not relevant able to empty too)
I can't use the ESP12F serial port. :(
What can I do?

Thanks, Gabor

The code not relevant
The COM port works and appear only if the ESP12 GPIO0 connected to GND and after reset.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and the main problem. **So the esp8266 consume bigger than the USBtoSerial adapter capacity. You need an external 3.3V power source (or battery).**
Thanks.